# Proxy Azure SQL database with firewall enabled on IP range

Tags: sql-server, firewall, azure, proxy, haproxy

I have following setup

- Azure SQL Database with firewall enabled, so that it will allow connections only from 104.x.x.x IP addresses
- Azure hosted Linux VM, within the same location as Azure DB, with external IP 104.x.x.x
- Local Linux VM, able to connect Azure VM through vnet, with external IP address 91.x.x.x

Goal is to be able to connect Local VM to SQL DB, using Azure hosted VM as a proxy.

I tried to setup it in two ways, with Nginx + RTMP Streaming Module as described here [Using a TCP proxy to connect to SQL Database over VPN](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql-database/using-a-tcp-proxy-to-connect-to-sql-database-over-vpn/ba-p/390962) , with following `nginx.conf`

```
events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}
stream {
  upstream sqlvm {
    server sqldb.database.windows.net:1433;
  }
  server {
    listen 1433;
    proxy_pass sqlvm;
  }
}
```

And second way with HAProxy in `tcp` mode.

```
listen sqldb
    bind *:1433 
    mode tcp
    server sqldb sqldb.database.windows.net:1433 check port 1433 inter 1000
```

In both cases, connecting with SQL client (e.g. `sqlcmd`) fails in the same way.

```sh
# 10.x.x.x is the IP of Azure VM in this setup
$ sqlcmd -S 10.x.x.x,1433 -d dbName -U user@sqldb.database.windows.net -P password
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Cannot open server 'sqldb' requested by the login. Client with IP address '91.x.x.x' is not allowed to access the server.  To enable access, use the Windows Azure Management Portal or run sp_set_firewall_rule on the master database to create a firewall rule for this IP address or address range.  It may take up to five minutes for this change to take effect..
```

Same command works, when executed on Proxy VM.

So somehow, *Azure SQL knows original client IP address* and blocks it, even though it is going through proxy.

How is that possible, given that we proxy on TCP level? Is there a workaround / working configuration for this setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the answer to this question is in the docs on [Azure SQL Connectivity Architecture](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connectivity-architecture#change-azure-sql-database-connection-policy).

> Connection policy
>
> Default: This is the connection policy in effect on all servers after creation unless you explicitly alter the connection policy to either Proxy or Redirect. The default policy isRedirect for all client connections originating inside of Azure (for example, from an Azure Virtual Machine) and Proxy for all client connections originating outside (for example, connections from your local workstation).

Meaning first connection goes through proxy, but after redirect it bypasses proxy altogether.

In the case of above setup, solution was to move Proxying VM outside of Azure. It could be also done, by changing DB connectivity mode to Proxy mode (but in exchange for the performance penatly)